# Project Euler: #5 (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So I`m trying to solve [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=5) and I have a solution:

```
def SmallestMultiple():
Nombre = 1
while Nombre != ((Nombre % 1 == 0) and (Nombre % 2 == 0) and (Nombre % 3 == 0) and (Nombre % 4 == 0) and (Nombre % 5 == 0)
and (Nombre % 6 == 0) and (Nombre % 7 == 0) and (Nombre % 8 == 0) and (Nombre % 9 == 0) and (Nombre % 10 == 0)
and (Nombre % 11 == 0) and (Nombre % 12 == 0) and (Nombre % 13 == 0) and (Nombre % 14 == 0) and (Nombre % 15== 0)
and (Nombre % 16 == 0)and (Nombre % 17 == 0)and (Nombre % 18 == 0) and (Nombre % 19 == 0) and (Nombre % 20 == 0)):
    Nombre +=1

if Nombre == ((Nombre % 1 == 0) and (Nombre % 2 == 0) and (Nombre % 3 == 0) and (Nombre %   4 == 0) and (Nombre % 5 == 0)
and (Nombre % 6 == 0) and (Nombre % 7 == 0) and (Nombre % 8 == 0) and (Nombre % 9 == 0) and (Nombre % 10 == 0)
and (Nombre % 11 == 0) and (Nombre % 12 == 0) and (Nombre % 13 == 0) and (Nombre % 14 == 0) and (Nombre % 15== 0)
and (Nombre % 16 == 0)and (Nombre % 17 == 0)and (Nombre % 18 == 0) and (Nombre % 19 == 0) and (Nombre % 20 == 0)):
    return Nombre
print SmallestMultiple()
```

I'm sure that it works, but it is computationally expensive and Python can't run it. 
Can anyone help me compress it whilst using while loops?
Thanks!

Comment: Please improve your indentation. And then rewrite your code entirely. Nobody needs that many conditions on an if-statement, ever. Hint: Use a loop.

Comment: You realize that anything which is mod 2 is also mod 4, mod 8 and mod 16, right? Focus on prime numbers!

Comment: you should use a loop.

Comment: Project Euler's problems aren't that much about coding, but about thinking first. Bruteforcing won't get you far. Think about prime factors, least common multiple, etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Computing_the_least_common_multiple

Comment: how can this work, you are comparing numbers with booleans

Comment: Look here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lcm%281%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20%29 This is the solution and how to get it.

Comment: `print (2*2*2*2*3*3*5*7*11*13*17*19)`

Comment: Please listen to @njzk2.

Comment: @njzk2 I disagree with the looping, he should just think about the problem first and then you can solve it in 30 seconds on a calculator.

Comment: @Hyperboreus : yes, but you are not really helping him do that, now, are you?

Comment: @njzk2 Trying to push him into the direction of the LCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in terms of prime factors. I.e., 6 is 2 x 3, so the desired must have 2 & 3 as factors.

9 is 2 x 3 so the desired number must have 2 factors of 3 in order to be divisible by 9

The rest is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this! As this gives you the results a bit quicker and there is not need for so may loop iterations.

```
import time
#Recording start time of the program
start=time.time()
#logic to find  the number
for i in range(200000000,999999999):
    if i%1==0 and i%2==0 and i%3==0 and i%5==0 and i%7==0 and i%11==0 and i%13==0 and i%14==0 and i%16==0 and i%17==0 and i%18==0 and i%19==0 and i%20==0:
        print("The largest number that is divisible by all number between 1-20 is",i)
        break

print("Execution time of program is",time.time()-start)
```